# How to pass the single parameter to custom attribute directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make validation directive for elements generated by ng-repeat (validate common logic). And now my problem is: how to group this elements by this ng-repeat cycle?

I decided to set some unique name on my validation directive to differ elements of different ng-repeats.
So how cat I pass this name?

For example ng-model takes object, and I need just string.

Comment: you could pass that as `prop="myObject.prop"` that will pass desired property.you must have define isolated scope with prop in your directive like scope: { prop: '='}..

Comment: So,  if I make this in .js:
angular.module('app').directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { prop: '=' },
 ...
 }
});
I could do this in .html:
<div my-dir="someString" ...>

Comment: you could also do `<div my-dir="someObj.somePropOfObj" ...> `

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar : And how to get it in directive controller, by "prop"?
What would be if I define several properties in my isolated scope?
Or "prop" is keyword like "this"?

Comment: you could easily get that that object property value inside your directive controller by doing `scope.prop` by the way mine last comment has wrong directive markup..here is corrected one `<div my-dir prop="someObj.somePropOfObj" ...> `

Comment: You meant that directive can access values of any attribute on neighbor elements?! Yeah, I can use it! :)
But it's still interesting how to make somethind like <input ng-model="param"/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88116/discussion-between-alex-silkovsky-and-pankaj-parkar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass single value in attribute directive (like `ng-model="myModel"`) we can use that fact that directive can read values of any neighbor attribute of the host element INCLUDE IT'S OWN. 
So if we do something like `<div my-directive="someValue">...</div>` we can read "someValue" in directive linking function via attributes array. 
[Documentation example](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom).